# Auto Column width script not working but Font and alignment are

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below script to try and format font , alignment and also column widths as various inputs are made daily some with conditional formatting and some free entry by many people in different locations.  The Font and Alignment parts are working exactly on all 5 sheets in the spreadsheet but for some reason I am getting the below error on the column width part but with various changes I still cannot see my error.
TypeError: Cannot find function autoResizeColumn in object Sheet,Sheet,Sheet,Sheet,Sheet,Sheet,Sheet. (line 7, file "Font + Alignment")

```
function onEdit()   {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets(); 
  var cell = ss.getRange("C6:U39");
      cell.setFontSize(12);
      cell.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      sheet.autoResizeColumn("A:U");    
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Notice line 3 added [0]
and line 7 changed to 1 for column 1

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeColumn(Integer)

```js
function onEdit()   {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
  var cell = ss.getRange("C6:U39");
      cell.setFontSize(12);
      cell.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      for (var i = 3; i < 22; i ++){ 
sheet.autoResizeColumn(i); }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is now working but only on Column 1 of the 1st sheet not Column C:U on all of the sheets, however font and alignment are still working on all of the sheets .

Comment: The method `.autoResizeColumn` only works on 1 column at a time. You need to loop over the columns to apply it to each column. Add this to your code `for (var i = 3; i < 22; i ++){ sheet.autoResizeColumn(i); }`

Comment: added @JamesDonnellan addition to above.